# How to get the menu key from the json in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want the get the "menu1" or "menu2" fields and so on, how to do it in angularjs?
the json is following:

```
{
"menu1": [
   {
     "item": "1",
     "Auth": "content/articleList",
   },
   {
     "item": "2",
     "Auth": "content/articleList",
   }],
 "menu2": [
   {
     "item": "3",
     "Auth": "publish/cacheSetting",
   },
   {
     "item": "4",
     "Auth": "publish/juggleList",
   }]
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this?

Comment: the "menu1" or "menu2" is the tile of the real menu,and the "item" is its submenu

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, menu) in menus">
  {{ key }}
  <div ng-repeat="item in menu">
    {{item.item}} : {{item.Auth}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Service and want to use it in a Controller then you'd do the following to load JSON in the service, and call it from a Controller.

```
App.factory("MenuService", [ '$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getMenus: function() {
            return $http.get( '/menuService' );
        }
    }
}]);


App.controller("SomeController", ['$scope', 'MenuService', function($scope,MenuService) {
    $scope.doSomething = function() {
        MenuService.getMenus().success( result ) {
            $scope.menu1 = result.menu1;
            $scope.menu2 = result.menu2;
            // You got menu1 and menu2 now do something
        }
    }
}]);
```